# Android-Login with facebook unable to create a graphuser object

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am making an Android application where login with Facebook functionality exists.
I am able to login with that, but the problem is that `GraphUser` object is not getting created...
Code:

```
 public class FBDemo extends Activity
    {
        private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
        private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
        private TextView userInfoTextView,txt;
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(FBDemo.this, callback);
            uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.authButton);
            txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
            userInfoTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.userInfoTextView);
            txt.setText("login");
            authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status"));
        }
        private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
                txt.setText("Logout");
                userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Request.newMeRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), new GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
                {
                    GraphObject gph=response.getGraphObject();
                    Log.e("User Info", "User Info" + user);
//                  Log.e("graphobject ", ""+gph.toString());
                }
            }).executeAsync();
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
                txt.setText("Login");
                userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
        private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
            }
        };
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (session != null &&
                   (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
                onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
            }
            uiHelper.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            uiHelper.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            uiHelper.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

    }
```

Once I get a `graphuser` object then I can access the name, email and other details...

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't quite follow you. Especially the "the object is not created". What have you tried? What error messages are shown? Exceptions?

Comment: In onSessionStateChange function if state is opened the i am making a call to get user information. That GraphUser is not getting created.i mean is was null all time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following way to obtain the Graph User

```
private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
            edit.putString("access_token", session.getAccessToken());
            edit.putString("expires", session.getExpirationDate() + "");
            edit.commit();
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                    if (user != null) {
                        String firstName = user.getFirstName();
                        String lastName = user.getLastName();
                        String id = user.getId();
                        String email = (String) user.asMap().get("email");

                        Log.i("facebookid", id);
                        Log.i("firstName", firstName);
                        Log.i("lastName", lastName);
                        Log.i("AccessToken", session.getAccessToken());
                        Log.i("Email", email);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", firstName);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

            });

        } 

        else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```